# Is there any way to use img alt as tooltip?

Tags: html, image, alt

I have a page with **many** images, here is an example:

```
<section>
    <div><img src="capas/livro1.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e a Pedra Filosofal"></div>
    <div><img src="capas/livro2.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e a Câmara Secreta"></div>
    <div><img src="capas/livro3.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e o Prisioneiro de Azkaban"></div>
    <div><img src="capas/livro4.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e o Cálice de Fogo"></div>
    <div><img src="capas/livro5.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e o Enigma do Príncipe"></div>
    <div><img src="capas/livro6.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e a Ordem da Fênix"></div>
    <div><img src="capas/livro7.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e as Relíquias da Morte"></div>
    <div><img src="capas/livro8.jpg" alt="Pai Rico, Pai Pobre"></div>
    <div><img src="capas/livro9.jpg" alt="Quem Mexeu no Meu Queijo?"></div>
    <div><img src="capas/livro10.jpg" alt="O Guia do Pão Duro"></div>
.
.
.
</section>
```

I'd like to show tooltip without using `title`. Is it possible using only HTML, CSS or JavaScript?

Something like this:

[image: Tooltip]

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are ways and it is possible. In fact, there have been many, many questions about making tooltips without using `title` on Stack Overflow. Did you find these questions' answers lacking?

Comment: Also consider if you are using the `alt` attribute for a tool tip you are probably using it incorrectly. It should be used as an alternate description of the image for screen readers etc. It should NOT be used to provide additional info like a title. That is the purpose of the `title` attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgoing the fact that `alt` should not be used for a tool tip, really you should use `title`, or better still `figure` and `figcaption`, you can do this with CSS alone.

Use the `:after` psuedo element with `hover` then use `content:attr(alt)` to get the value of the alt attribute.

**EDIT : Annoyingly this doesn't work in microsoft browsers** as they don't support `img::after`.

```css
.covers>div {
  /*Tooltip will be positioned relative to this*/
  position: relative;
}

/*Tooltip magic*/
.covers img:hover:after {
  display: block;
  content: attr(alt);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
  border-radius:2px;
  padding:2px;
}

.covers img {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 300px
}
```

```html
<section class="covers">
  <div><img src="capas/livro1.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e a Pedra Filosofal"></div>
  <div><img src="capas/livro2.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e a Câmara Secreta"></div>
  <div><img src="capas/livro3.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e o Prisioneiro de Azkaban"></div>
  <div><img src="capas/livro4.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e o Cálice de Fogo"></div>
  <div><img src="capas/livro5.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e o Enigma do Príncipe"></div>
  <div><img src="capas/livro6.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e a Ordem da Fênix"></div>
  <div><img src="capas/livro7.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e as Relíquias da Morte"></div>
  <div><img src="capas/livro8.jpg" alt="Pai Rico, Pai Pobre"></div>
  <div><img src="capas/livro9.jpg" alt="Quem Mexeu no Meu Queijo?"></div>
  <div><img src="capas/livro10.jpg" alt="O Guia do Pão Duro"></div>
  . . .
</section>
```

Here's how I'd actually do it with more semantically correct tags

```css
.covers>figure {
  /*Tooltip will be positioned relative to this*/
  position: relative;
}

.covers>figure>figcaption {
  display:none;
}


/*Tooltip magic*/
.covers figure:hover > figcaption {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.8);
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

.covers figure {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="covers">
  <figure><img src="capas/livro1.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e a Pedra Filosofal cover">
    <figcaption><strong>Harry Potter</strong> e a Pedra Filosofal</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="capas/livro2.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e a Câmara Secreta cover">
    <figcaption><strong>Harry Potter</strong> e a Câmara Secreta</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="capas/livro3.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e o Prisioneiro de Azkaban cover">
    <figcaption><strong>Harry Potter</strong> e o Prisioneiro de Azkaban</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="capas/livro4.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e o Cálice de Fogo cover">
    <figcaption><strong>Harry Potter</strong> e o Cálice de Fogo</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="capas/livro5.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e o Enigma do Príncipe cover">
    <figcaption><strong>Harry Potter</strong> e o Enigma do Príncipe</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="capas/livro6.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e a Ordem da Fênix cover">
    <figcaption><strong>Harry Potter</strong> e a Ordem da Fênix</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="capas/livro7.jpg" alt="Harry Potter e as Relíquias da Morte cover">
    <figcaption><strong>Harry Potter</strong> e as Relíquias da Morte</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="capas/livro8.jpg" alt="Pai Rico, Pai Pobre cover">
    <figcaption>Pai Rico, Pai Pobre</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="capas/livro9.jpg" alt="Quem Mexeu no Meu Queijo? cover">
    <figcaption>Quem Mexeu no Meu Queijo?</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure><img src="capas/livro10.jpg" alt="O Guia do Pão Duro cover">
    <figcaption>O Guia do Pão Duro</figcaption>
  </figure>
  . . .
</section>
```

Going this route you can have additional styling within the tool tip if needed

Comment: First code did not work. 
And I agree with you that semantically using `figure` and `figcaption` makes more sense. I will do it, thanks.

Comment: Don't you think it's redundate to write the captions twice? I mean, we have the same thing inside `alt` and `figcaption`.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right regarding the first snippet. Microsoft browsers seem to have issue with `::after` when applied to image tags. In my opinion it shouldn't be redundant as `alt` should provide a text description of the image . e.g : "Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone book cover", not a caption or tool tip. That is the role of the `title` attribute or `figcaption` tag which would contain "Harry Potter and the Philosophers Stone". The content may be similar but the roles have important differences.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp) on how to create tooltips using only HTML/CSS

Here's a snippet from the site:

```
<style>
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
 
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This site really helped me. I am studying about it. Thanks